# Stack too deep, difference between memory variables local variables

Tags: evm

Got a "stack too deep" error, and saw on stack exchange that I could try and use memory variables instead of local variables, and moved 8 uint into a uint[8], no error anymore. Why does that work while using individual unit did not?

Code example

```
uint a;
uint b;
uint c;
uint d;
uint e;
uint f;
uint g;
uint h;
```

"using too many variables, stack too deep"

and with

```
uint[8] memory abcdefgh;
```

no problem

Comment: Can you add more detailed code/ context? The declarations on themselves seem to work fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, your individual primitives are local variables, placed on the program stack. The maximum stack depth is limited: those variables may make your program reach that limit, generating a stack overflow error.

In the second case, by default, Solidity will generate code to store the array in **storage**, which has virtually an infinite capacity. Therefore, there won't be any error.

You can make that explicit with the `storage` attribute. You can also tell the compiler to place the array in memory with the memory specifier: `uint[8] memory abcdefgh`.